# Win32API - How to get file name of process from process handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

How can I get the file name of process from a process handle? I'm using Win32 C++ (Visual C++ Express Edition).

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198.aspx). Available as of Windows 2000.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileNameEx(
  __in      HANDLE hProcess,
  __in_opt  HMODULE hModule,
  __out     LPTSTR lpFilename,
  __in      DWORD nSize
);
```

Use `NULL` for the second parameter to get the name of the EXE file.

Comment: this only works with a 32 bit process for 32 bit processes, in the other case you will get an error. If you non the less want to do it do it with GetProcessImageFileName

Comment: From the docs: "The **GetModuleFileNameEx** function is primarily designed for use by debuggers and similar applications that must extract module information from another process". Also: "Functions like Get­Module­File­Name­Ex and Create­Tool­help­32­Snapshot are designed for diagnostic or debugging tools" from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131

Comment: What's your point, @Paul?

Comment: My point is that it's not the ideal function for production usage. I'd suggest using **QueryFullProcessImageName** instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. Indeed, Steve suggested the same thing 13 years ago.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't mention the reason or the difference. I thought it's worth mentioning to help make a more informed decision for people who find this question in the future.

Answer (score 11):

The [`GetProcessImageFileName` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217%28VS.85%29.aspx) retrieves the name of the executable file for the specified process handle (WinXP, Server 2k3 or later), as does [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Vista and 2k8 or later.

Comment: **The `GetProcessImageFileName` function returns the path in device form, rather than drive letters.** - that's nasty. `GetModuleFileNameEx` is the right way :)