# Validate Strong Name of Running Assembly

Tags: .net, validation, strongname

Is it possible for one to check the strong name of a .NET application that is already currently running separately from your own running applications process?

---

EDIT: For clarification, a solution that does not require a hard coded path to the executing assembly would be the most ideal solution.

---

EDIT #2: Is there any way to do this **without** using reflection?

Comment: I think you can. As you dont want to change something in the running file. Looking is not disturbing the process of a running application.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly. Check if a specific process has a strong name? Get the FullName of the EntryAssembly of a specific process? You don't want to hard code the assembly path but do you have the process name or process id of the process you want to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this give you what you are looking for?

```
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(Process theprocess in processlist)
    {
        string strongName = "N/A";
        try
        {
            strongName = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(theprocess.MainModule.FileName).FullName;
        }
        catch
        {
            // System process?
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Strong Name: {2}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, strongName);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this without reflection?

Comment: I know of no other way to do this.

Comment: +1 and accepted as I used this as a solution for the time being. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Without reflection:

If you know the process, you know the filename. If you know the filename, you can [process the PE headers to find the strong name signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/01/26/361109.aspx).

Comment: For getting the file name from the process handle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219951/win32api-how-to-get-file-name-of-process-from-process-handle

Comment: +1 - I didn't accept this as I will only be able to use it at a later stage (if at all), but thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
public static bool IsStrongNamed(string assemblyPath)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        byte[] publicKey = a.GetName().GetPublicKey();

        return publicKey.Length > 0;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}

public static bool GetStrongName(string assemblyPath)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);

        return a.FullName;
    }
    catch { return string.Empty; }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this without reflection?

Comment: You mean without ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom? Why don't you want to use that? It allow you to inspect an assembly without really loading it in your process.

Comment: It still unfortunately locks the file of the process.

Comment: Then you could use andras solution with PE headers, but in that case it might be easier to just copy the dll in a local folder and then use ReflectionOnlyLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think the solution to Your problem is the AssemblyName class.
First

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName = nameUWant); //maybe single or default?
```

then with each process take Process.Modules to get dlls or exes loaded by this process.
After You obtain the name You want. (the module has name property).
Then use

```
AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName().GetPublicKeyToken() != null
```

This should work.
hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

If by "strong name" you mean the exe name:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

if (Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever.exe").Length > 0)
{
     //do something

}
```

Comment: strong name as in application title?